# Flutter / Android(Kotlin) - Background Services

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, background-service

**GOAL**:
Write a service that performs HTTP request to an IoT device API periodically. Occasionally push notifications.

**WHAT I'VE DONE**:
I've figured out the code required to create push notifications and applying the intent to open the host app when clicked.

**TESTED SO FAR**:
I tested some demo code for starting media player services and playing an mp3. But they all were killed once the app was killed.

Now I'm looking into WorkManager for Android. Is this the best service for this use case? Every minute or so it can perform a simple HTTP request?